# How to use c# Regular expression to replace a substring inside a round brancket

Tags: c#, regex

Assume I have an original string like this:

```
Whatever here is (this is what i want to be replaced) Whatever here is
```

I want to replace

```
this is what i want to be replaced
```

with

```
'this is what i want to be replaced'
```

I want the result to be:

```
Whatever here is ('this is what i want to be replaced') Whatever here is
```

What I should use the regular expression to make it work?

The Regular Expression pattern is always confusing me.

Comment: text.Replace("(", "('").Replace(")", "')");

Comment: For something like this I agree with @PeterLillevold - the built-in String functions are easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You search for this regex:

```
\(([^)]*)\)
```

And replace by:

```
('$1')
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uO0bL3/1)

**Code:** You can use [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx) method:

```
string repl = Regex.Replace(input, @"\(([^)]*)\)", "$1");
```